# Linear transformation of a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Assuming $X$ follows a multivariate normal distribution with mean vector $0$ and variance-covariance $S$ (i.e., $X\sim N_n(0,S)$), I know that $$\mathbb{P}(X\leq t)=\mathbb{P}(BX\leq Bt)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq Bt),$$ for a $n\times n$ matrix $B$ and vector $t$, where $Y:=BX\sim N_n(0,BSB')$. I ran the following commands in R but got different results:

```
library(mnormt)
t <- c(.2,.75)
B <- matrix(c(2,-.5,-.5,1.5),nrow=2)
Bt <- c(B %*% t)
pmnorm(t,mean=rep(0,2),varcov=S)                  # P[X<=t]
pmnorm(Bt,mean=rep(0,2),varcov=B %*% S %*% t(B))  # P[Y<=Bt]
```

results:

```
[1] 0.3984423
[1] 0.2642346
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I also tried `mvtnorm` library, but got the same results.

Comment: How did you get from $X\leq t$ to $BX\leq Bt$?  I believe that would only hold if the entries of $B$ are positive, which is not the case in your code.

Comment: @felipeh, Not necessary, for example `B <- matrix(c(2,1,1,1.5),nrow=2)` the two probabilities are: `0.3984423` and `0.604285`.

Comment: Ah, yeah I suppose that there's only a lower bound -- if $X\leq t$ then $BX\leq Bt$.  One perhaps only expects equality if the matrix and its inverse both have positive entries (are there any examples of such matrices with off-diagonal entries?) . In any case the problem is that $X\leq t$ and $BX\leq Bt$ are related in a complicated way and one shouldn't expect anything like an equality.